# Enabling Anonymous REST on Production Org

Tags: apexrest

Can we enable anonymous REST API access for master instance? I mean the production instance. I tried the steps given here

http://wadewegner.com/2013/03/creating-anonymous-rest-apis-with-salesforce-com/

but, it is not working. When I say not working, I mean, that I get empty string in response.

Please help.

Comment: You can certainly do that for a Prod Org - what isn't working? Can you post the URL you are using - that's often when folks trip up.

Comment: The url looks like http://thedomain.force.com/wgapp/services/apexrest/CampaignsAPI, where "thedomain" is our custom domain which I can't disclose here.

Comment: could you add what error/response you are getting when accessing the API

Comment: No error, no data in response. I get empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Check the security settings for the Site Guest User under Public Access Settings - sounds like it can't see the objects you are trying to access.

Comment: The site was showing two urls thedomain.force.com and thedomain.secure.force.com. I was using thedomain.force.com earlier and now, using thedomain.secure.force.com worked. Thank you.